# Include external html table data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ok, so I have a HTML jquery tablesorter webpage. Instead of embedding all the "td" tags inside the same file, I would like to load them from a separate file. The reason being the data is very large, and it is required for modularity. Here is what I am trying so far....

```
        <div id="demo"><table class="tablesorter">
<script src="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.js"> w3.includeHTML();</script>
        <br>
                <!-- Table Head -->
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Sensor</th> <!-- disable dragtable on this column -->
                        <th class="drag-enable">c1</th>
                        <th class="drag-enable">c2</th>
                        <th class="drag-enable">c3</th>
                        <th class="drag-enable">c4</th>
                        <th class="drag-enable">c5</th>
                        <th class="drag-enable">c6</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <!-- Table Footer -->
                <tfoot>
                    <tr><th>c1</th><th>c2</th><th>c3</th><th>c4</th><th>c5</th><th>c6</th><th>c7</th></tr>
                </tfoot>
                <!-- Table Content -->
                <tbody w3-include-html="C:\Users\user\Desktop\new_test\tabledata.html"> 
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Comment: So, what issue you are facing?

Comment: If you have a lot of data then you shouldn't be loading it using javascript. The browser will non-responsive until the data loads. I would recommend you only load data as necessary to the browser (something like 20 rows at a time)...

Comment: i can paste it direct inline, hence using on file. Its more about modularity as the table datafile is modified by another program. It is not an enormous amount of data, ie there is no noticeable un-responsive from browser

Answer (score 1):

I got it working like this:

```
            <table id="table" class="tablesorter">

                <script src="columndata.js"></script>

            </table>
```

Then in the .js file i just have a variable and document.write. Very simple and works effectively.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you have not initialized `w3.includeHTML()` method properly.

Issue is you need to initialize `w3.includeHTML();` at the end of your html code

Try below code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.js"></script>
    <body>
    <div id="demo">
    <table class="tablesorter">        
            <br>
                    <!-- Table Head -->
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Sensor</th> <!-- disable dragtable on this column -->
                            <th class="drag-enable">c1</th>
                            <th class="drag-enable">c2</th>
                            <th class="drag-enable">c3</th>
                            <th class="drag-enable">c4</th>
                            <th class="drag-enable">c5</th>
                            <th class="drag-enable">c6</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <!-- Table Footer -->
                    <tfoot>
                        <tr><th>c1</th><th>c2</th><th>c3</th><th>c4</th><th>c5</th><th>c6</th><th>c7</th></tr>
                    </tfoot>
                    <!-- Table Content -->
                    <tbody w3-include-html="C:\Users\user\Desktop\new_test\tabledata.html"> 
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
      <script>
        w3.includeHTML();
      </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Try this and let me know in case you face the issue.

Comment: hmm, still no luck

Comment: What issue you are facing?